# (WinHttp.WinHttpRequest): Ошибка поддержки безопасных каналов

Tags: telegram-bot, администрирование, internet-explorer, 1с, telegram

нужна помощь знатоков. 
Создал Телеграм бота в 1С 8.2 Обычные формы, некоторое время бот получал сообщения пользователей, а потом вдруг перестал.

ввожу в Internet Explorer **`https://api.telegram.org/bot<Мой токен>/getUpdates`** выводит:
***Internet Explorer не может отобразить эту веб-страницу.***

ввожу в люб другом браузере тоже самое ответ приходит корректный.

в самом 1с в exception попадает :

> **{ОбщийМодуль.skdTelegram.Модуль(629)}: Ошибка при вызове метода контекста (Send): Произошла исключительная ситуация
>   (WinHttp.WinHttpRequest): Ошибка поддержки безопасных каналов**

Код

```
WinHttp = Новый COMОбъект("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");    
    WinHttp.Option(2, "utf-8");     
    WinHttp.Open("GET","https://api.telegram.org/bot<МойТОкен>/getUpdates?offset=119801317&", 0);

    WinHttp.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "ru");
    WinHttp.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "Windows-1251");
    WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Language", "ru");
    WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Charset", "Windows-1251");
    WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application / x-www-form-urlencoded; charset = Windows-1251");        

    WinHttp.Send();
```

PS (IE Версия 8 ) может изза этого?

Comment: https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/1024217/  попробуй такой вариант

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, у вас в соединение не прописан SSL.

Comment: Можете подробнее описать решение? (P.S : не работал с SSL)

Comment: Можете показать код, который используется для отправки запроса?

Comment: @Anonymouse, решили проблему?

Comment: Нет проблема все еще актуальна( . Код добавил

Comment: Аа-а, вы используете COM объект для выполнения запроса.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте встроенными средствами платформы:

```
ЗащитаSSL   = Новый ЗащищенноеСоединениеOpenSSL();
Соединение  = Новый HTTPСоединение("api.telegram.org", , , , , , ЗащитаSSL);

Заголовки = Новый Структура();
Заголовки.Вставить("Content-Type", "application / x-www-form-urlencoded; charset = Windows-1251");
Заголовки.Вставить("Accept-Language", "ru");
Заголовки.Вставить("Accept-Charset", "Windows-1251");
Заголовки.Вставить("Content-Language", "ru");
Заголовки.Вставить("Content-Charset", "Windows-1251");

Запрос = Новый HTTPЗапрос("/bot<МойТОкен>/getUpdates?offset=119801317&", Заголовки);

HTTPОтвет = Соединение.Получить(Запрос);

ОтветКоторыйПришел = HTTPОтвет.ПолучитьТелоКакСтроку();
```

Comment: @Anonymose, получилось?

Comment: Нет, 8.2 не поддерживает SSL (

Comment: @Anonymouse,
аа-а, у вас "старушка" платформа.